# can't install PPA's in UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I've been trying to install ppa's for a while and I'm a little desperate; -; , because I need to do a job and I can’t install it at all (ah, hi this and my first post aki hhihi, I just made an equi account in the community and downloaded the ubunto shortly) I installed the most updated version of the focal fossa, I am trying to install the OBS open broadcaster software, whenever I install ppa from the command line of the same error "Repository does not have a release file" I tried to look for some updates but most sites only have for ubunto 15.00 ; -;
I don't know what to do because I already tried this method here: https: //itsfoss.com/repository-does-not-have-release-file-error-ubuntu/

but it doesn't solve anything ._. , I think I will have to download the previous ubunto, like going from 20.04 to 15.00 but I don't know how to do this; -; help

this error for all unofficial ppas that I download more or less
(oh and also sorry for my english! it's not my native language, i'm using google translator :v)

AAAWWWo i understand a litle now :v, thaks for the answers people youre awnsome,you answered very quickly even,it work!

Comment: Which exactly PPA? Which URL?

Comment: a lot , i have other probllems too but i wil make other posts to tell, soo in the moment i im tryin to add the obs pp'a .-.

Comment: @N0rbert how can i add the obs then? '-'

Comment: @pLumo i im stil confuse but thanks ._.

Comment: @pLumo its like, im not tryin to update, im tryin to instal, men why its so confuse, in win i just download a .exe file and pow just run and stuf

Answer (score 3):

1. OBS Studio (Version 25) is already in the Ubuntu 20.04 Deb repositories. A PPA is not needed.

   `sudo apt install obs-studio`

   You can also use the Ubuntu Software application to install the Deb.

   - Version 26.0 is in the Ubuntu 20.10 repositories. Version 26.1 is being tested for Ubuntu 21.04. For newer Deb-based software, use a newer release of Ubuntu.
   - A PPA is not a *software package*. A PPA is a not-official (testing/development) *archive* from which you can get software packages. Instructions that tell you to add PPAs are generally suspect. You can add PPAs if you wish (it's your system), but it's *optional*. Few users *need* PPAs.
2. OBS Studio (Version 26.1 as of 01.12.2021) is already available as a self-updating Snap for all supported releases of Ubuntu.

   `sudo snap install obs-studio`

   You can also use the Ubuntu Software application to install the Snap.